# What is a better way to write this comparative PowerShell script?

Tags: arrays, xml, powershell, for-loop

I'm new to PowerShell and I'm sure I'm not using best practices here. I've been working on this PowerShell script to compare two XML files. I start out by looping through each of the XML files and throwing the data into PS objects:

Here are some samples of the XML data:

**XML file 1**

```xml
<RESULTS>
    <ROW>
        <COLUMN NAME="ATTR1"><![CDATA[123456ABCDEF]]></COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="ATTR2"><![CDATA[1.0.4.0]]></COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="ATTR3"><![CDATA[Google.com]]></COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="ATTR4"><![CDATA[Lorem ipsum]]></COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="ATTR5"><![CDATA[This is some text]]></COLUMN>
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
        <COLUMN NAME="ATTR1"><![CDATA[123456ABCDEF]]></COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="ATTR2"><![CDATA[2.0.0.1]]></COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="ATTR3"><![CDATA[HelloWorld.com]]></COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="ATTR4"><![CDATA[Lorem ipsum]]></COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="ATTR5"><![CDATA[This is some text]]></COLUMN>
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
        <COLUMN NAME="ATTR1"><![CDATA[123456ABCDEF]]></COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="ATTR2"><![CDATA[5.6.7.0]]></COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="ATTR3"><![CDATA[foo_foo_6 (2).org]]></COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="ATTR4"><![CDATA[Lorem ipsum]]></COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="ATTR5"><![CDATA[This is some text]]></COLUMN>
    </ROW>
</RESULTS>
```

**XML File 2**

```xml
<applications xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <application>
        <name>Google.com</name>
        <version>1.2.0.0</version>
    </application>
    <application>
        <name>HelloWorld.com</name>
        <version>2.0.0.1</version>
    </application>
    <application>
        <name>FOO_FOO.org</name>
        <version>6.2.0.1</version>
    </application>
</applications>
```

**Creating arrays/objects filled with XML data**

```sh
# assign all output from `foreach` loop to `$array1` - XML file 1
$array1 = foreach($row in $xmldata1.RESULTS.ROW){
  # create new object with the pertinent details as property values
  [pscustomobject]@{
    Name = $row.COLUMN.Where{ $_.NAME -eq "ATTR3"}.'#cdata-section'
    Version = $row.COLUMN.Where{ $_.NAME -eq "ATTR2"}.'#cdata-section'
  }
}

# assign all output from `foreach` loop to `$array2` - XML file 2
$array2 = foreach($row in $xmldata2.applications.application){
  # create new object with the pertinent details as property values
  [pscustomobject]@{
    Name = $row.name
    Version = $row.version
  }
}
```

This is the script I'm wondering how to write more effectively. It simply loops through `$array1` and compares it with the data in `$array2`. If there is a match in the name, and a mismatch in the version, then it will store those values in a PS object.

**Script I want to improve**

```sh
#loop through array 1
for($i = 0; $i -le $array1.Length; $i++)
{
    #loop through array 2
    for($j = 0; $j -le $array2.Length; $j++)
    {
        #if file name in array 1 matches a name in array 2...
        if (($array1.name[$i] -eq $array2.name[$j]) -or ($array1.name[$i].Substring(0, [Math]::Min($array1.name[$i].Length, 7)) -eq $array2.name[$j].Substring(0, [Math]::Min($array2.name[$i].Length, 7))))
        {
            #then, if that file names version does not match the version found in array 2...
            if($array1.version[$i] -ne $array2.version[$j])
            {
                #create new object        
                [pscustomobject]@{
                    Name = $array1.name[$i]
                    Name2 = $array2.name[$j]
                    Version = $array1.version[$i]
                    Version2 = $array2.version[$j]            
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, there are some names that don't match perfectly. So I use the `-or` operator and throw this line in my first `if-statement` to compare the first 7 characters of the file name in each array to see if there's some kind of match (which, I know there are):

```sh
($array1.name[$i].Substring(0, [Math]::Min($array1.name[$i].Length, 7)) -eq $array2.name[$j].Substring(0, [Math]::Min($array2.name[$i].Length, 7)))
```

Whenever I add that line though I get the following error for only *some* of the data objects in the arrays. The script will return some objects, but most of the time my console pane will be filled with the following error:

**Error**

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:8 char:13
+         if (($array1.name[$i] -eq $array2.name[$j]) -or ($array1 ...
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

I don't even know what it's talking about. Cause when I extract that line and put actual indices in it, it works fine.

**Example**

```sh
if($array1.name[1020].Substring(0, [Math]::Min($array1.name[1020].Length, 7)) -eq $array2.name[2500].Substring(0, [Math]::Min($array2.name[2500].Length, 7))){
```

So, I'm stumped. Is there a better way to compare these two arrays and get a similar output?

Comment: One reason, likely, could be because at some point in your loop in `$array1.name[$i]` or `$array2.version[$j]` either `$i` or `$j` is an index out of bounds and powershell defaults to `$null.SubString(...)`. If you share minimal examples of the XMLs you want to compare we might be able to help you and maybe give you a better alternative

Comment: Added XML examples @SantiagoSquarzon

Comment: Your code works perfect, the problem is the use of `-le` instead of `-lt` in the `for` loops :)

Comment: You definitely want to use `$array1[$i].name` in place of `$array1.name[$i]`, latter is insanely inefficient

Comment: " there are some names that don't match perfectly" - can you provide samples of such almost-matching names?

Comment: nice catch @MathiasR.Jessen, I believe he means `foo_foo_6 (2).org` and `FOO_FOO.org` as an example of strings that would match using substring

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon I can't believe it was that simple lol. 
@MathiasR.Jessen Wow, that output returned MUCH faster. Thanks for that tip. 

However, my script still did not pick up `foo_foo_6 (2).org` and `FOO_FOO.org`. But it picked up something similar, so I'm confused why didn't pick up the former? (i.e. `fo_foofoo_3.org` and `fo_foofoo.org`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this could work and might be a more direct way to do it, this method would not require you to do the object construction of the first XML. Hopefully the inline comments explains the logic.

```sh
:outer foreach($i in $xml1.results.row) {
    $name = $i.Column.Where{ $_.NAME -eq 'ATTR3' }.'#cdata-section'
    $version = $i.Column.Where{ $_.NAME -eq 'ATTR2' }.'#cdata-section'
    foreach($z in $xml2.applications.application) {
        # check if they have the same version
        $sameVersion = $version -eq $z.Version
        # check if they have the same name
        $sameName = $name -eq $z.Name
        # if both conditions are `$true` we can skip this and continue with
        # next item of outer loop
        if($sameVersion -and $sameName) {
            continue outer
        }
        # if their first 7 characters are the same but they're NOT the same version
        if([string]::new($name[0..6]) -eq [string]::new($z.Name[0..6]) -and -not $sameVersion) {
            [pscustomobject]@{
                Name     = $name
                Name2    = $z.Name
                Version  = $version
                Version2 = $z.Version
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The result of this would be:

```sh
Name              Name2       Version Version2
----              -----       ------- --------
Google.com        Google.com  1.0.4.0 1.2.0.0
foo_foo_6 (2).org FOO_FOO.org 5.6.7.0 6.2.0.1
```

See [**Using a labeled continue in a loop**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_continue?view=powershell-7.2#using-a-labeled-continue-in-a-loop) which describes and explains the use of `continue outer` in this example.

Comment: Really appreciate both of your guy's help! @SantiagoSquarzon

Comment: my pleasure @Crimp, your question was very well formulated and interesting so thank you ;)